How to verify refurbished hard drives?
I bought a refurbished 3.5" hard disk recently and connected it to PC using external hard disk enclosure.
But I am worried about 2 things:

I want to verify it actually has storage space it claims to be. I heard sometime they show fake capacity but has much less space than they show in Windows.
For this, I need a tool to fill hard disk with test data completely. Once it's full, I need the tool to read the whole hard disk and verify that data is still there.

It has no bad sectors.


Are there ways to verify these things?
I'd like to stress the the supposed duplicate does not address these questions.

@spikey_richie I want to fill hard disk up to 100% capacity with test data. And then verify it exist in second step. I feel this is the full-proof way to test it. I need a tool for it. The linked question should address it.

Unfortunately the best method is try to fullfill it completely: lot of fake disks and USB drives simply mount the firmware of a bigger device of the same manufacturer, so you can't discover it unless he randomly try to address some data to a memory area which is not really present on the board.
Another good way on USB and SSD devices could be open it up, count the memory chips phisically presents (the big black rectangular things), and google the chip model printed on them to discover how big are them. Just as an example, a 512gb SSD could internally have 8x 64gb memory chip solded on them
EDIT: Just a warning notice for other people, as a user noted to me: Opening the device may break it's warranty, if it's not a refurbished one!

"Unfortunately the best method is try to fullfill it completely" - That's what I want to do. Is there is a tool that can do it for me?

Opening up an SSD to count the surface-mounted chips may void your warranty.

@CodePanda I used Random Data File Creator, it's very old but still working.
It's a command-line tool.
http://www.bertel.de/software/rdfc/index-en.html
Another way could be using a security software to safely erase disk, they usually write random data to all the surface (probably giving you an error when they meet the effective end of the fake disk).
I only know "Darik's Boot and Nuke" (it's a live distro, needs an usb key) but there will be probably many others. Be sure to nuke the correct drive and not your main disk :-)

@spikey_richie yeah it void the warranties, but it's already a refurbished drive. I think official warranty has already gone

@spikey_richie From my understanding, it only tries to write data but it doesn't verify that current data is not overriding previous data internally
